# JS, вынос в отдельный файл

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe

Категорически приветствую,

В "head" имеется:

```
<script>
      swiffyobject = {"as3":false,"frameRate":24,"frameCount":471 ...туева хуча строчек...
    </script>
```

После в body используем "swiffyobject"

```
<script>

      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {});

      stage.start();
    </script>
```

Подскажите каким образом swiffyobject из head можно вынести отдельный файл?

Спасибо

P.S.
Пытаюсь импортировать анимацию из Adobe Flash CS6 в HTML5 и сотни строк кода мешают в основном файле .html

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо

```
<script>
  swiffyobject = {"as3":false,"frameRate":24,"frameCount":471 ...туева хуча строчек...
</script>
```

пишем:

```
<script src="swiffyobject.js"></script>
```

создаём файл `swiffyobject.js` с содержимым:

```
  var swiffyobject = {"as3":false,"frameRate":24,"frameCount":471 ...туева хуча строчек...
```

Comment: Не совсем то, мне нужно вынести    
swiffyobject = {"as3":false,"frameRate":24,"frameCount":237,"backgroundColor":-1,"frameSize":{"ymin":0,"xmin":0,"ymax":8000,"xmax":4800},"fileSize":62936,"v":"7.4.0","internedStrings":

Comment: Поправил ответ ...

Comment: Спасибо, все работает